# SQLITE with python : Adding the database name in SELECT statement

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I am using sqlite3 with python, and after connecting to the database and creating a table, sqlite3 shows an error when I try to execute a SELECT statment on the table with the name of the databse in it :

```
con = sqlite3.connect("my_databse")

cur = con.cursor() 

cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE my_table ... ''') 

cur.execute("SELECT * FROM my_database.my_table") # this works fine without the name of the database before the table name
```

but I get this error from sqlite3 :
no such table : my_database.my_table

Is there a way to do a SELECT statment with the name of the database in it ?

Comment: is this a typo? your first line uses `"my_databse"`. Also, since you've already connected to that database, why are you trying to use the database name in the select statement?

Comment: Why do you need to do that? That notation is for DBMSs that give you access to several databases with a single connection. But  a `sqlite` file contains only one database. There is no point in prefixing it to the table name. If you are doing this because you plan to migrate your code to a multi-user database at some point, it might be better to do your development on a database that is more like the intended target. Naming the tables will be the least of your problems migrating from `sqlite`.

Comment: Oh sorry abou that, but that's not the problem, the code works fine @MZ

Comment: @BoarGules This should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @BoarGules I am working with third party code ( that interacts with my python scripts) that generates SQL statements (prefixed with the database name) that i can not change, i can only work the SQLITE3 database that I create

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no you can't do this with SQLite. This is because you already specify the database name with `sqlite3.connect()` and SQLite3 doesn't allow multiple databases in the same file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure of the database is in the same directory with the python script. In order to verify this you can use `os` library and `os.listdir()` method. After connecting the database and creating the cursor, you can query with the table name.

```
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM my_table')
```

Comment: The database is in the same directory of the python script, so i don't think that's an issue